# Two lines are removed with sed instead of one, why?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, variable

I am attempting to remove lines from this text file (`foo.txt`):

```
cat
mouse

animals: 2
```

I want to remove the two lines from the end:

```
‎
animals: 2
```

So I end up with this:

```
cat
mouse
```

However, when using `variable="$(sed '$d' foo.txt)"`, both lines appear to be removed, even though I only specified one `$d`. Even though this gives me the result I am looking for, I can't help but wonder why this is happening. When attempting to NOT store the output in a variable, I get the output I expect to see:

```
user$ sed '$d' foo.txt
cat
mouse

user$
```

Oddly enough, using `$ sed '$d;$d' foo.txt` only removes the `animals: 2` line, and not the newline before it.

Could somebody de-mystify this for me? Thanks.

For the record, BSD sed is being used in this case.

Comment: Command substitution -- the `$( )` bit -- removes *all* trailing newlines from what it captures. Therefore, blank lines at the end will get removed before the value is stored in the variable. (Note: you probably want *one* newline removed from the end, since lines in a file are normally terminated by newlines, but variable values are not.)

Comment: Thanks Gordon. For the most part, that makes sense. Is there a way for me to retain the newline in between `animals: 2` and `mouse`, while storing the entire thing in a variable? I am using `echo "$variable"` in my testing.

Comment: Your issue is with command substitution removing newlines, just like Gordon pointed out. Note also that the `d` command in `sed` ends the current cycle. Therefore, on the last line, the code `$d; $d` would only ever run _one_ `d` command, never two. It's unclear what the second `d` would be able to accomplish anyway, as the first `d` removes the last line.

Comment: Process substitution will do what you want, e.g. `IFS= read -rd '' var < <(tac foo.txt | sed '1,2d' | tac); echo -n "$var"`